# Spring database configuration issue

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to `Spring-MVC`, i am trying to create a `Spring-MVC` project that uses `annotation` in `controller` and also creates `databases`.

The application works fine, when i write all the `xml` code in `spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file, but when i separate `spring database connection xml` and `spring servlet xml` file, it stops working.

The following code successfully creates tables in database, but it fails to load controllers, it gives me `404 not found` page when i try to hit any controller.
If i comment `<listner>` code in my `web.xml` file it successfully loads all the controllers, but no database operations performed.

Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here.

**web.xml**

```
<!--  JPA  -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>



<!--  Servlet Dispatcher  -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Spring.xml**

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.evantage.models" />
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springDB" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
    <!-- This produces a container-managed EntityManagerFactory; rather than 
        application-managed EntityManagerFactory as in case of LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="/WEB-INF/persistence.xml" />
    </bean>



   <jpa:repositories base-package="com.evantagesoft.springmvctiles.repository"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                      transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

**Spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.evantage.controllers" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="preparerFactoryClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringBeanPreparerFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- View Handler -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="xml" value="text/xml" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="less" value="text/html" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                <property name="viewClass"
                    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
            </bean>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <!-- <property name="prefix" value="/"/> -->
                <property name="prefix">
                    <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
                </property>
                <property name="suffix">
                    <value>.jsp</value>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add context:component-scan base-package="controller package" in dispatcher servlet xml to make it work.
Component scan is required to scan the package and register your controller classes

Comment: Thanks bro, its working fine now :) Is there any place where i can learn these `Spring-xml` related things

Comment: You can refer spring mvc documentation. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html